# How to distribute two apps in one certificate in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a question that is how to distribute two apps in one production certificates ? But first app is using apple push message services but seconds app is not? Otherwise both two application is using push message services ?

I feeling embarrassing what should i do ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it.  Each push notification certificate is tied to a single application.  The Apple probisioning portal makes that very clear,  when in order to create the certificate you first have to define a unique application id.

Comment: so, when you create a new certificate and provisioning for new app. How to distribute old app if you want to upgrade new version ? Must You revoke certificate and create new ? But if the old app is using push message ? i'm still not clearly for this ?

Comment: @NguyenDuc If by new app you mean a new version of an old app, then it's the same app, and you can use the same certificate for the new version. If it's a different app (with a different application id), you'll need a new certificate.